# Does $http work in phonegap?

Tags: android, http, angularjs, cordova

I'm using angular-phonegap-seed to write a mobile app, and was wondering if there were any known issues with using $http.

My controller code is called on the push of a button.

```
$http.get('http://192.168.1.2:8000/request_token').success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    $scope.token = 'sucess: ' + data + ' ' + status + ' ' + headers + ' ' + JSON.stringify(config);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    $scope.token = 'error: ' + data + ' ' + status + ' ' + headers + ' ' + JSON.stringify(config);
});
```

At the moment, `request_token` on the server is simply a file with a dummy token in it.

The server acknowledges getting the request in the console and responds with 200. 
The phonegap app on android however responds:

```
error: undefined undefined undefined {"transformrequest": [NULL], "transformresponse": [NULL], "method": "GET", "url": "http://server-ip:8000/request_token", "headers": {"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"}}
```

Can I use the regular $http.get() method in phonegap, or do I have to use a phonegap api?

Comment: I've got the same problem with the latest PhoneGap and AngularJS. I've tried with web browsers as well as CordovaBrowser, this only happens when the app is installed on the device. Have you found anything useful on this?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it turns out to be that I forgot about whitelisting the domains I was sending request to.

Check out the [Domain Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide) and see if it helps.

Comment: Putting in whitelist helps me exactly.